# Hive equivalent for this Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

Can anyone help me with this sql query, I have no idea, what this (+) operator does, but I found on the internet that its a synonym for oracles outer join. But I cant figure out how to implement this with my query. Please help me with this.

```
Select t1.a1,t1.a2,t1.a3
From t1,t2,t3
where t1.a1 =t3.c1(+)
AND t2.b1(+) = t1.a1
AND t2.b2(+) =1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Oracle outer join syntax shouldn't be used any more in the first place. You should also change your Oracle quey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outer joins:

```
Select t1.a1, t1.a2, t1.a3
From t1 left join
     t3
     on t1.a1 = t3.c1 left join
     t2
     on t2.b1 = t1.a1 and t2.b2 = 1;
```

This is the right way to write the query in any database.  The `(+)` syntax is obsolete.

Comment: I added the "left join" bit to the t2 line.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out and used left outer join in the same way and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.a1, t1.a2,t1.a3 
from t1 left join t3 on t1.a1 = t3.c1
left join t2 
on t2.b1 = t1.a1
and t2.b2 = 1
```

The (+) sign is an Oracle-specific notation for an outer join. I believe its kind of not used a lot anymore...

[more info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3178)